# Raspberry Pi 2 max USB current

Tags: power, power-supply

I'd like to power an RPLiDAR (5V @ 230mA) and a Pixy CMU Cam5 (5V @ 120mA)

Is this possible I can give it a 5V 4A powersupply if necessary.

Will this burn out the Pi over time?

Comment: Amp is how much power can be provided to create watts. Voltage is the frequency which must match the requirements at best. Ohms law is `Amp x Volt = Watt` Only giving too much volts will burn it but taking too much power (amp) can stress cables and PCB which may burn. But the PI is protected at 2AMP (2A x5v = 10Watts max power consumption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean mA (rather than Mega) there should be no problem (PS permitted). The total current of the Pi2 is limited to 2A by the polyfuse. The Pi uses ~500mA leaving 1500mA for peripherals.